# Dependency Injection - Static Functions

Tags: php, static, dependency-injection

I get the basic idea behind Dependency Incjection (e.g. for Databases), but i couldn't figure out how to use it with static functions:

```
class Foo{
    private $id; 
    private $class_variables,...;
    private $db;
    public function __construct($db,$id,$class_varibles,...)
    {
        $this->db=$db;
        //Assignments
    }

    public static function Get_By_ID($id)
    {
     //No DB-Connection here
     return new Foo(?);
    }
}
```

Is the only way to do this the following?

```
class Foo{
     ...
     public static function Get_By_ID($db,$id)
     {
        //Do work here!
        return new Foo($db,$id,$class_variables,...);
     }
```

It seems like a lot of additional work for several static functions.
Also:

```
$f = new Foo($db);
```

will only be able to create new Objects with the "$db" it has saved in (private $db)

```
$b = $f->Create_Bar();
```

How can you solve this problem?
Is the only way:

```
$b = $f->Create_Bar($db_for_bar);
```

Additional: How to do it with an static function?

```
$b = Foo::Create_Bar($db_for_foo,$db_for_bar);
```

What am I missing?

(Additional 2:

```
 $f = new Foo($db); //Dependency Injection ($db is saved in $f, and is the database-link for example)
 $f->Create_Bar($db_for_bar); //OK - No Problem
```

but what if "Create_Bar" is called inside "Foo"

```
 $this->Create_Bar(???) //Where does the $db_for_bar come from?
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good solution, I don't understand why you say it doesn't work:

```
class Foo{
     ...
     public static function Get_By_ID($db,$id)
     {
        return new Foo($db,$id,$class_variables,...);
     }
```

Comment: It will work, but is it good that i have to use
     $b = Foo::Create_Bar($db_for_foo,$db_for_bar);
for example, if a _Foo_ creats a _Bar_ (What if it uses several "subclasses"? Do I have to use a function which is only "overhead" with databases for different Objects)
Also: $f = new Foo($db); What if $f->Create_Bar($db_for_bar); (non-static function) is called inside the class like: $this->Create_Bar(???); Where do I get the $db_for_bar from?

Comment: OK I understand it's not very practical. I think the root problem here is that you have a DB object in every model class, and using DI with model classes is hard (because you use `new MyModel` everywhere in the code). If I were you, I wouldn't bother too much with DI, or I would change the design of the model classes (using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) for example) so that model classes don't hold a DB object.

Comment: (in the second case, the DB object would be inject in "repositories", not in model classes, and repositories are like services so it's easy to use DI with them)

Comment: Well I'm the author of http://php-di.org, I'm all for DI. However it becomes really useful and appropriate when you follow other design patterns and separation of concerns. So I'd say you'll get a lot of benefits if you dive in fully with all best practices. If you are on a small project, or don't want to invest too much time, then using singletons is fine and gets the job done. If you're starting a big/complex application, then singletons (and your current model architecture) will soon create problems. So it depends on your need, there's a choice and not "one good way" of doing things.

Comment: Years later I finally got the chance to use php-di and I really enjoy how it works!

Comment: @SpazzMarticus thank you I'm always happy to hear that :)

Comment: I expected something like Foo::Get_By_ID($id); so $db and other services are autowired from container. If he is using the framework of course.